# When should I pick Surge, and when Promote, in Dominon?

Tags: league-of-legends

Often, when playing supports in Dominion, like Lux or Janna, I like picking Ghost, then a spell that will help the team (directly or indirectly) as opposed to just me. In many guides I have read, people insist that Garrison is not as useful as other spells I could pick.

What parameters should I consider when trying to pick between Surge and Promote?

Is it better to pick Surge as a carry, or is Promote equally viable?

What should I pick when playing support? Should I go for something else entirely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So your basic question seems to be: `Surge or Promote?`  This is a rather strange question as those two summoner spells fit very differently into the current Meta-game.  In fact, I don't believe there is ever a hero I could imagine having to choose between those particular spells as they serve *very* different roles.  So instead, let's assume that you want to know when these two spells are appropriate (and not make a choice between them).

#### Surge

Surge is a rather recent introduction into LoL and is still having its place in the meta-game examined. While it does act as a much needed steroid for a number of champions missing one (eg. Twisted Fate or Teemo), it suffers on champions who require a lot of farm (i.e. most carries). In comparison to spells like Ignite and Exhaust, Surge (while scaling better) just doesn't guarantee kills the same way through early/mid-game.  Now, it's true that Dominion has a shortened early/mid-game, but it's just as true that it has a shortened late game (where this spell really shines).  As a result Surge is frequently not the best choice for champions (even carries).

- *When to get it?* When you're the main DPS and you don't have a built-in steroid
- *When to avoid?* When you're a carry who needs kills to make it to late game

#### Promote

Promote is another spell which hasn't yet found a good place in the overall meta.  However, having been around longer, there are more obvious cases where people use it (i.e. in Dominion going bottom against a Champ who has trouble clearing lanes early on, like Tryndamere or Yorick).  Given Promote's role in taking down towers, it's no real surprise you see it more often in Dominion than Summoner's Rift.  Usually, you want Promote to push your creep wave into a tower allowing for a better engagement at a node.  This frequently means you find Promote on Champions who have trouble clearing lanes or who are good initiators.  A Champion that requires more farm or is main DPS (i.e. a carry) is a less likely place to find promote as it doesn't fit their role well.

- *When to get it?* When your team lacks a lot of lane clearing ability (or against a team which lacks it)
- *When to avoid?* When you're filling a more important role (i.e. Carry)

#### Garrison

I'm surprised you're reading a lot of information that Garrison is a poor choice; it is quite a good spell.  The problem with Garrison is that it really only shines is defending nodes in Dominion.  Very frequently people don't do this (usually because it's less exciting).  However, there are a large number of places where your team can really benefit from Garrison (solo bot, or even defending top).  Garrison can break a channel (from further range), stop a wave push, or even heal a node, all very useful things in Dominion.  Even if it only forces the other team to break off an engagement then it is directly translating into victory points (something few other spells do).

- *When to get it?* When you're running a 3 Node defensive strategy or against a team with a lot of floaters (e.g. Rammus)
- *When to avoid?* When you're filling a more important role (i.e. Carry) or you're going for a more aggressive strategy (i.e. running floaters)

#### Flash vs Ghost

Both of these are excellent spells (and there are even times when you might get both), but in Summoner's Rift, at least, the current meta-game has stabilized on Flash being invaluable.  This is largely due to two factors:

1. Flash lets you get out of (or into) range of abilities and champions
2. Flash lets you "jump" over the twisting terrain in SR

However, in Dominion both of these reasons are less effective.  The terrain in the Crystal Scar has fewer features you can "jump" with Flash, the faster game play means champion deaths are less impactful (thus saving, less important).  While still a great spell, Flash is nowhere as dominant in the Crystal Scar as it is in Summoner's Rift.  Instead, two other features dominate The Crystal Scar which make Ghost a frequently more picked spell:

1. Non-linear attack routes
2. Contested towers

Having multiple paths to engage (and less vision) often means you are forced to move to positions very quickly.  This is the reason champions like Rammus are so frequently banned.  What's more, it's frequently a strategy to rush to the top tower at the opening of the game to assert the defender's advantage.  In a rush strategy (fairly common) it is necessary that most of the top defenders have Ghost to out pace the other team.  As a result Ghost may not enjoy the same dominance that Flash has in SR, but is still a powerful spell (and a frequent choice).

- *When to get it?* Both Flash and Ghost can be great spells on any Champion
- *When to avoid?* Only when you have something which is much higher priority or more synergistic with your strategy (like Zombie Karthas was).

Comment: Oh my god, you're back!! :D

Comment: @Mana I lurk sometimes...

Comment: mmmm... the garrison is good in dominion for ganking people on the tower aswell since it does seriously less damage. If you can just pop it nuke down the defender, you have time to spare to cap it and still survive.

Comment: @tzenes `Instead, two other features dominate Summoner's Rift which make Ghost a frequently more picked spell` <-Do you mean Dominion here? It sounds like you do, but I didn't want to edit that without checking. Also, what do you mean by the term "floaters"?

Comment: @Fallen, yes.  Floater here is synonymous with roamer.

Comment: @tzenes Aaah okay, I hadn't heard that term used before in association with LoL.

Comment: @Fallen last night someone used the term "Reel," which I had never heard in my 500+ games.  Apparently, it means: "let the lane push toward your tower."

Comment: After the flash nerf, I find it much less essential and often prefer ghost.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally get promote 100% of the time if I'm following the "push-bottom-meta" if I'm the one bot.

To make it clear:

1. Surge: Increases ap & as on your character
2. Promote: Turns siege minion into anti-turret cannon
3. Garrison: On friendly capturepoint - Increase attack speed and restores neutralisation / On enemy capture point - Reduce damage for 8s

(http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/ is the source for all the above)

So for a support Surge would be useless since it only effects you. Then it's a tossup between what you want and what your team needs. Promote helps you push overwhelmingly if the other team dosn't have it aswell, and garrison makes plays on and around the tower easier. So the answear isn't really straight forward, allthough many people value having promote as if the enemy team hasn't got it and your team has. The creepwave will be kept close to their tower.

On a carry the answear is boring... Since I'd say "it depends". Ask yourself: Which carry (some benefit more than others)? Dose anyone else have promote? Is your team already going to destroy minion-waves but struggle at the tower (or the other way around)?

So bottom line is concider your and the enemy team, use summoners to find advantage and as always coordinate your choices with your team.

Answer (score -4):

- *Best summoner spells*

I really suggest you to use **flash** and **ignite**. These can be used in every game. Maybe you want to change some of them, for example **smite** instead of **ignite**, if you will be jungling. What I'm trying to say is, especially **flash** is this game's most advantageous summoner spell and don't hesitate to use it either run from enemy or catch him.

- *Surge, promote, ghost*

When it comes **promote** and **surge**, I don't suggest both of them. Both spells will loss their influence in late game. Nevertheless, **ghost** is still a controversial issue whether you should use it or not. Because you will use it for catching the enemy or running from enemy. So, you had better use **flash** instead of **ghost**.

- *Supporting*

There is no specific champion you have to play with it, but generally supporters are based on "mana". For example, while playing Sona, you will be healing your premade all day long and in order to fulfill it, you have some mana lasting for a long time. Or supports prefer take the Blue(in jungle). It also prevents you last your mana for a long time. Supporters also have to have some "hp". You should not leave your teammates alone during the combat. So, your hp should be also high.

Evenly if you have a question, do not hesitate to ask it..

Comment: Your answer seems to be based on Classic, when my question is based on Dominion, where players can't jungle, and Ghost is more effective than Flash.

Comment: Why downvote? I want to emphasize that FLASH is better than GHOST because FLASH gives you the ability to move RAPIDLY and INITIALLY. On the other hand GHOST gives you no ability to run from enemy's ULTIMATE because it cannot make you replaced. GHOST is also useless in combats... I don't understand the point why players prefer GHOST instead of FLASH(Generally these players are noobs)

Comment: Again, I am talking about Dominion, not Classic. In Dominion, fights are not worth that much, and you are more interested in capping points than getting away from/chasing enemies. Not to mention, if you're slowed, Flash doesn't help as you're still slowed, but Ghost allows you to counter the slowing. Also, Ghost lasts longer, so it's a sort of "pocket Boots of Speed" with the added bonus of passing through creeps (which you can't do with Flash).

Comment: If we are talking about DOMINION, Ghost is needless because there are alreadly many points to boost your movement speed in the map. Furthermore, Ghost CANNOT remove the negative buffs or slows if you are in danger, just add extra movement speed to your base movement speed.

Comment: I did not say that it cancels the slows, I said it counters them, giving you more speed that you might escape. Also, no speed is enough in Dominion, in my opinion, and I'm sure most people would agree :)

Comment: -1 : I cannot agree saying flash is better than ghost. It always depends on the situation. I personally love ghost in dominion because mobility is a key factor to success, ghost allows you to "lane swap" (from bot to windmill) much faster. Saying flash ignite are the 2 spells one should always take shows clearly you don't take into consideration each champions specialty.

Comment: Dominion is not that simple. Purpose is not only being fast. Lane swap is effective but As I mentioned before, There is many points in the map accelerate you. In every case, FLASH is the MOST EFFECTIVE, MOST ADVANTAGEOUS and MOST SURVIVAL SPELL!!!

Comment: If you wish to hold extended conversations, rather than doing so in the comments please [make or find a related chatroom and continue the conversation there](http://chat.stackexchange.com/); the comments should be reserved for discussion of the answer's content, not name-calling.